# Zoom Into Image With OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have the following picture as an example:

529 x 550 px (100 %)

[image]

As a target I would like to have the image zoomed to about

150 %, but it should still be

529 x 550 px:

[image]

I was able to write the code using PIL, but I want to have it with Cv2. Can someone help me please?

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2 as cv

def zoom_at(img, x, y, zoom):
    w, h = img.size
    zoom2 = zoom * 2
    img = img.crop((x - w / zoom2, y - h / zoom2, 
                    x + w / zoom2, y + h / zoom2))
    return img.resize((w, h), Image.LANCZOS)

img = Image.open("image.png")

img = zoom_at(img, 264.5, 275, 1.5)

img = img.save('image_zoomed.png')
```

@Ofer Sadan

```
import cv2 as cv


def zoom(img, zoom_factor=1.5):
    return cv.resize(img, None, fx=zoom_factor, fy=zoom_factor)


img = cv.imread('original.png')
# Original: 529 × 550


height, width = img.shape[:2]


zoomed = zoom(img, 1.5)
# Zoomed: 794 × 825 


cropped = zoomed[0:550, 0:529] # Wrong area
# Now I want to crop the middle of the new image as variable.


cv.imwrite('zoomed.png', zoomed)
cv.imwrite('cropped.png', cropped)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a little snippet I used a while ago that I can't currently test so let me know if it actually works or not

```
import cv2 as cv

def zoom(img, zoom_factor=2):
    return cv.resize(img, None, fx=zoom_factor, fy=zoom_factor)
```

And you can crop before the zoom or after it as you wish:

```
img = cv.imread(img_path)
cropped = img[200:300, 150:250]
zoomed = zoom(img, 3)
zoomed_and_cropped = zoom(cropped, 3)
```

Comment: It's not working.. The output isn't centered and is not 529 x 550 px..

Comment: @vas0yxkwasdx you'll have to add your own math in so that the centering is exactly the same, I just gave you a start and an example

Comment: It works! Now I only need to know how to cut the middle of the image as 550x 529 px ... I updated the question :)

Answer (score 6):

There you go:

cv:

```py
import cv2 as cv

def zoom_at(img, zoom=1, angle=0, coord=None):
    
    cy, cx = [ i/2 for i in img.shape[:-1] ] if coord is None else coord[::-1]
    
    rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cx,cy), angle, zoom)
    result = cv2.warpAffine(img, rot_mat, img.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    
    return result
```

Laymans manual:

```py
import cv2 as cv

def zoom_at(img, zoom, coord=None):
    """
    Simple image zooming without boundary checking.
    Centered at "coord", if given, else the image center.

    img: numpy.ndarray of shape (h,w,:)
    zoom: float
    coord: (float, float)
    """
    # Translate to zoomed coordinates
    h, w, _ = [ zoom * i for i in img.shape ]
    
    if coord is None: cx, cy = w/2, h/2
    else: cx, cy = [ zoom*c for c in coord ]
    
    img = cv.resize( img, (0, 0), fx=zoom, fy=zoom)
    img = img[ int(round(cy - h/zoom * .5)) : int(round(cy + h/zoom * .5)),
               int(round(cx - w/zoom * .5)) : int(round(cx + w/zoom * .5)),
               : ]
    
    return img
```

```py
img = cv.imread('x3Lkg.png')
cv.imwrite('x3Lkg_zoomed.png', zoom_at(img, 1.5, coord=(264.5, 275)) )
```

[image: original image]

[image: zoomed image]

Comment: Nine answer, but I think you have a tiny mistake. `cx, cy = w/2, h/2` should be `cx, cy = (w-1)/2, (h-1)/2`. OpenCV warp conventions is that coordinate (0, 0) is the center of the top left pixel. The accurate center of the image is (`(w-1)/2`, `(h-1)/2`)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who does not want to the math manually this works for me.

```py
import cv2

def zoom_center(img, zoom_factor=1.5):

    y_size = img.shape[0]
    x_size = img.shape[1]
    
    # define new boundaries
    x1 = int(0.5*x_size*(1-1/zoom_factor))
    x2 = int(x_size-0.5*x_size*(1-1/zoom_factor))
    y1 = int(0.5*y_size*(1-1/zoom_factor))
    y2 = int(y_size-0.5*y_size*(1-1/zoom_factor))

    # first crop image then scale
    img_cropped = img[y1:y2,x1:x2]
    return cv2.resize(img_cropped, None, fx=zoom_factor, fy=zoom_factor)

# read original 
img = cv2.imread('original.png')

# call our function
img_zoomed_and_cropped = zoom_center(img)

# write zoomed and cropped version
cv.imwrite('zoomed_and_cropped.png', img_zoomed_and_cropped)
```

**Notice** that I first cropped and then rescaled. It is more efficient and you will notice it when dealing with a live video feed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @Tyler2P I tried formulating the answer better. Hope this helps.

Comment: Sometimes it does not work as it give a resulting image having a different width / height than the original.

Answer (score 2):

For putting a specific point in the input image at a specific point in the output image, with a precise scale factor, you would want to use `cv.warpAffine`.

This function requires you to build a transformation matrix. That is easy.

```py
def translate(tx=0, ty=0):
    T = np.eye(3)
    T[0:2,2] = [tx, ty]
    return T

def scale(s=1, sx=1, sy=1):
    T = np.diag([s*sx, s*sy, 1])
    return T

def rotate(degrees):
    T = np.eye(3)
    # just involves some sin() and cos()
    T[0:2] = cv.getRotationMatrix2D(center=(0,0), angle=-degrees, scale=1.0)
    return T
```

```py
im = cv.imread("x3Lkg.png")
(ih,iw) = im.shape[:2] # input height, input width

# parameters
scale_factor = 10
angle_degrees = 15
(ow, oh) = (529, 550) # output size
(icx, icy) = (459, 352) # zoom onto that pixel in input
(ocx, ocy) = ((ow-1)/2, (oh-1)/2) # put there in output (it's the exact center)
```

```py
# the transformation, read from right to left
H = translate(+ocx, +ocy) @ rotate(degrees=angle_degrees) @ scale(scale_factor) @ translate(-icx, -icy)

# assume that H is affine, not a full homography
assert np.allclose(H[2], [0,0,1])
M = H[0:2]
```

```py
# produce the picture
# use INTER_LINEAR, INTER_CUBIC, INTER_LANCZOS4 for smooth interpolation
# use INTER_AREA for scale factors much below 1
out = cv.warpAffine(im, dsize=(ow,oh), M=M, flags=cv.INTER_NEAREST)
# imshow(out)
```

[image: INTER_NEAREST]

[image: INTER_LANCZOS4]

Comment: This method can replace `cv2.resize` and `imutils.rotate` and don't require slicing. Not as intuitive though.