# How to create zoomed-in views of an image

Tags: r, image-processing, imagemagick, zooming

Environment: Windows 10 / software: Irfanview, Imagemagik, R

For a PPT presentation, I'd like to create several (3-4) images obtained by zooming into a base image, keeping the image size the same and letting the periphery disappear as I zoom in. Or even better, do this as an animated (GIF) image. The idea it to create the impression of walking into the scene.

I can try to do this manually, by expanding and taking screenshots, but I wonder if there is any better way.

Here is my original; it's 1023 x 722px.
[image]

And then a manual zoom, perhaps the final step.
[image]

**Edit**:
I can make this more specific, showing what I've done so far using the R `magick` package.  Below I read in the image, and draw a grid over it, for calculating a zoom path.

```
library(magick)
temple <- image_read("TempleOfTime.png")
# draw a grid
temple |> image_draw()
lines <- seq(100, 1200, 100)
abline(h=lines, v=lines)
text(15, lines, lines, cex=2, pos=4)
text(lines, 10, lines, cex=2)
# make the fig 'origin' at 15, 650, 
points(c(0,15), c(0,650), pch = 15, col = "red", cex=4)

# define a path for the zooms, going from 'start' to 'center'
center <- c(300, 440)
points(300, 440, pch = "+", col = "blue", cex=4)
start <- c(600, 650)
points(600, 650, pch = "+", col = "green", cex=4)
text(rbind(start, center), c("start", "center"), cex=2, pos=3)
```

This gives the image below.  Then, what I don't know is how to use the `magick` functions to zoom in along a path heading toward `center` from `start`.

I have to use `image_resize()` to enlarge then `image_crop()` to trim off the outside, keeping the total size the same as the original.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Zoom Into Image With OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050464/zoom-into-image-with-opencv)

Comment: did you mean: *imagemagick* -- did you mean to look for software recommendations, or do you actually plan to solve this by programming?